# Looping through unique lines in a txt file with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, xslt

I am looping through tab-delimited lines in a txt file. This txt file is the output of an xml/xslt process and has duplicates. Below I am looking for a solution with the txt file, but solutions using XSLT are just as appreciated. Please see example txt file.

txtfile.txt: line 3 is a duplicate of line 1

```
hello@example.com  running  1111
puppy@kennel.com   running  9876
hello@example.com  running  1111
husky@siberia.com  shutdown 1234
puppy@kennel.com   running  9876
hello@example.com  running  1111
```

**My question is:** Can duplicate lines be skipped in a loop so that the loop only processes unique lines? In this case, how to configure to loop lines 1, 2, 4 and skip lines 3, 5, 6?

My current working loop which reads duplicates:

```
while read name status num
do
    echo "<tag1>"
    echo "<tag2>"$name"</tag2>"
    echo "<tag3>"$status"</tag3>"
    echo "<tag2>"$num"</tag2>"
    echo "</tag1>"

done < txtfile.txt
```

In my txtfile there are hundreds of lines and nearly half are duplicates, so this is a huge problem for me! Any ideas/solutions appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: probably use a sorted unique list by sth like `<(cat txtfile.tx | sort | uniq)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read that file via `sort -u` to eliminate duplicate lines:

```
sort -u /your/file | while read ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using awk:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++{print "<tag1>\n<tag2>" $1 "</tag2>\n<tag3>" $2 "</tag3>\n<tag2>" $3 "</tag2>\n</tag1>"}' file
<tag1>
<tag2>hello@example.com</tag2>
<tag3>running</tag3>
<tag2>1111</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
<tag2>puppy@kennel.com</tag2>
<tag3>running</tag3>
<tag2>9876</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
<tag2>husky@siberia.com</tag2>
<tag3>shutdown</tag3>
<tag2>1234</tag2>
</tag1>
```

The condition `!a[$0]++` evaluates to true the first time each line is seen and false thereafter. When the condition is true, the output is printed.

The basic principle is that the contents of the line `$0` is used as a key in the array `a`. If there's a change that the spacing may differ between records, you could use `!a[$1,$2,$3]++` instead, which will count lines as being the same as long as the 3 fields are the same, regardless of the spacing between them.

Comment: Great solution! Worked perfectly.. though I'm a bit too lazy to write/edit the extensive awk command if I can go about another way (sort -u by posted by Costi). I will definitely up-vote when I have the ability at 15 rep.